# Error in writing files

Tags: python, file, sorting

I want my function to sort data and print it into a file of the users choice. This is the code I have. Instead of printing the information it is printing 'None' into the file. Also the file that it should be printing into should be one that the user selects but instead it is printing into a file calling write_sorted_data. what is the problem with my code that is causing this?

```
options_functions = {'i':student_lab_average,
       'ii':student_prog_average,
       'iii':mid_average,
       'iv': overall_grade,
       'v':weighted_total_score
             }
options_strings = {'i':'lab average',
       'ii':'program average',
       'iii':'midterm average',
       'iv': 'final grade',
       'v':'weighted total score'
                 }

def sorted_data(student_scores):

    print("This option is for sorting students data and printing in a   file")
    print("(i) lab average, (ii) program average, (iii) midterm average, (iv) final, (v) weighted total score")

    user_sorted_data=input("Select one of the options (i-v):")

    write_sorted_file=input("What file would you like this written into?")

    print("You have selected sorting student data upon      "+options_strings[user_sorted_data])
    f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
    f.write(str(options_functions[user_sorted_data](student_scores)))
    f.close()
```

This is how i am calling the function

```
elif(ch== 'e'):
    print(" ")
    student_name=input("Type the student's last name:")
    print(" ")
    scores= get_data_for_student(student_name,mid1,mid2,final,homework,labs,program1,program2,program3,participation)
    f=open('write_sorted_file', 'w')
    print(" ")
    f.write(str(sorted_data(scores))) 
    print("Your file has been written.")
    f.close()
```

Comment: have you tried debugging yourself? at least by including print statements, this way you can see where your coding is not working as expected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  This does not include the functions included in your functions dictionary, and I suspect that you're not putting them in properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `return` statement in the  function `sorted_data(student_scores)` so it will return with an implicit return value of `None`.

You first write to a file within that `sorted_data(student_scores)` function. Then you again write to the same file the return type of the function. This is `None` for the reason stated.

So, the final thing (over)written to that file is the return type of the function  i.e `None` , since you didn't open the file with append "a". So None is the end state contents of the file.

The double write (both within the function, and followed by a write of its return value) is not recommended even if the function had a return value. It's too mistake prone a design.

Also if you want the file written to to be user defined, use the variable representing the user defined name of the output file , i.e. `write_sorted_file` , when opening it, not the statically defined filename 'write_sorted_file' in quotes.

Comment: How do you suggest i write my return statement? And which portion should i remove from the menu function that calls it? @paisanco

Comment: What was the design intent? Did you intend to compose content in the sorted_data function  to be written out? It should return some data structure containing the content, but unless you plan to append more data after the function call , it's not clear why to do it that way.

Comment: It is only intended to get the user to select what information they want printed into the file out of the options provided. Appending is not necessary as the user can write to different files. I have removed the  ' ' around the write_sorted_file to enable this. @paisanco

Comment: I would definitely recommend just localizing all file open, write, and close operations within the function, return nothing, and pass parameters into the function to specify what should be written. No file opens/closes in the calling if/else block. I'd suggest an object oriented approach over that if you know Python objects however. But that would be getting beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:**

The reason you're writing `None` into the file is that you're writing the output of your function `sorted_data`. `sorted_data()` doesn't have a return statement, so it returns `None` by default.

**Question 2:**

You are currently writing into a file called 'write_sorted_file' as specified here:

```
f=open('write_sorted_file','w')
```

If you want to write to the file that you specify within the variable `write_sorted_file`, then you would want to remove those single quotes:

```
f=open(write_sorted_file,'w')
```

**Other issues:**

However, with those two questions, your code still seems to be quite a ways from doing what you want. For instance, nowhere in your code are you actually sorting anything. Also, you are writing out to a file both in your main function and also in the function `sorted_data` that you defined. I'm pretty sure that's not what you're intending to do.